# Weird console.log behavior in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, css, devtools

In Chrome Dev Tools, you `console.log` an Array. It shows: `(4)[Location, Location, Location, Location]`: perfect, that's what I expected.

You click on it, to reveal the elements, and it shows:

[image: screenshot]

How is this possible?

Comment: `What the hell?` was much better `:D`

Comment: Thats because you probaly update that array somewhere in your code. So when `chrome` logs it, its length = 4. When you open it the array has been manipulated and the length now = 2.

Comment: @Ionut that , from an array of 4 elements, it shows 2 elements when you click on it and it says `length: 2`

Comment: @Red sure. that actually makes sense

Comment: When you initially log the array it has 4 elements. At the moment you click the little triangle to expand it, the array has 2 elements. Hover over the little blue boxed i, it basically says exactly that (in a general way).

Comment: i'm rushing on a crazy deadline and have not time think properly. thanks you all people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when the element is edited after it was logged. Chrome just shows you a pointer to that element. If 2 and 3 are removed after `console.log()` they are shown in the preview, but not when you inspect the element.

Comment: If you want to log a snapshot of an object, you can clone it using `const clone = Object.assign({}, originalObject)`

Answer (score 1):

The `console` will log the `array`. You see three *properties* inside it. When you delete a property later on, and you open the `console`. You will only see the remaining *properties*.

See this snippet, and check the `console` in your browser.

```js
var array = [{name: 'helle'}, {name: 'Google'}, {name: 'Bonjour'}];

console.log(array);

delete array[2];
```

*Just a visualization of the anwser given by @Felix Gaebler*